# How to Do Multiple Asyncronous Qunit Tests with A Set Up and Teardown Module

Tags: javascript, jquery, qunit

I'm struggling to get some async tests set up with Qunit. Don't know what's going on to be honest as I'm new to testing. I've looked up a few similar questions on SO but none seem to work for me.

```
(function(){

  var textBox, textArea,
     fixture = document.getElementById('qunit-fixture');

  QUnit.module( "module", {

    setup: function( assert ) {

      textBox        = document.createElement('input');
      textBox.type   = 'text';
      textBox.value  = '';

      textArea       = document.createElement('textarea');
      textArea.value = ' ';

      textBox.setAttribute("id", "textBox");
      textArea.setAttribute("id", "textArea");

      fixture.appendChild(textBox);
      fixture.appendChild(textArea);

    },

    teardown: function( assert ) {

      fixture.removeChild(textBox);
      fixture.removeChild(textArea);

    }

  });

  QUnit.asyncTest( "test a", function( assert ) {

    expect(1);

    setTimeout(function() {
      textBox.value = 'a'
    }, 250);

    setTimeout(function() {
      assert.deepEqual(textBox.value, 'a');
      QUnit.start();
    }, 500);

  });

  QUnit.asyncTest( "test b", function( assert ) {

   expect(1);

    setTimeout(function() {
      textBox.value = 'b'
    }, 250);

    setTimeout(function() {
      assert.deepEqual(textBox.value, 'b');
      QUnit.start();
    }, 500);

  });

}());
```

When I run this in the browser it says: `1. module: test b(1)`, so I guess it's only the running the last test or the first hasn't finished or something? Confused, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm... I've copied your code into a test file and run it and everything works fine, I see both tests and both pass. That said, QUnit does allow you to rerun individual tests... can you check the URL in your browser? Does it indicate a test number to run? Are there any errors in the console?

Additionally, note that the `#qunit-fixture` div is automatically reset after each test in that module, so the `teardown` mehtod you have should not be necessary. Instead, you can simply add an input and textarea to that `#qunit-fixture` div in the HTML file and then let QUnit reset it for you.

My test.html file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/qunit-1.14.0.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="qunit"></div>
    <div id="qunit-fixture"></div>

    <script src="vendor/qunit-1.14.0.js"></script>
    <script>
      // your code here...
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah I found when I came back to this a few days later it seemed to work. I have know idea why though. Thanks for the info about the fixture being reset automatically, I will try that out. Thanks.